# OneWorld - Get stock on hand from other subsidiaries NSAPI1.0

Tags: netsuite, suitescript

I’ve written a function to retrieve either locationquantityavailable or locationquantityonhand from another subsidiary.

The assumption is the user has visibility of both subsidiaries, in a scenario where a sales order is being entered under Subsidiary A, and a SO item custom field is to show the items stock on hand in Subsidiary B.

At the moment I’m getting a null result from the saved search below. I’m sure I’m missing something very basic.

The logger line is correctly giving results:  Get Stock   Sub:36 Loc:16 Item:4448

I know there *IS* both onhand and available stock in the source sub/loc/item combination.

```
function getStock(sub, loc, itemid, available ) {
  try {
        var subsidiary = isNum(sub),
              location = isNum(loc), 
              item = isNum(itemid);
        if (subsidiary == 0 || location == 0 || item == 0) {return 0}

        var filters = [ new nlobjSearchFilter('subsidiary', null, 'anyof', sub ),
                        new nlobjSearchFilter('location', null, 'anyof', loc ),
                        new nlobjSearchFilter('internalid', null, 'is', itemid )];
        var columns = [ new nlobjSearchColumn('subsidiary' ),
                        new nlobjSearchColumn('location' ),
                        new nlobjSearchColumn('internalid' ),
                        new nlobjSearchColumn('locationquantityonhand' ),
                        new nlobjSearchColumn('locationquantityavailable' )];

        logger('Get Stock   Sub:'+subsidiary+' Loc:'+location+' Item:'+item);
        logger(filters);
        logger(columns);

        var res = nlapiSearchRecord('item',null,filters,columns);
        logger('Get Stock Search:');logger(res);
        if (res == null ) {
              return 0;
        }
        if (available) {
              return res[0].getValue('locationquantityavailable');
        }
        else {
              return res[0].getValue('locationquantityonhand');
        }
  } catch (err) { logger(err) }
```

}

Comment: Disregard... doh!!  'inventory' versus 'inventorylocation' in the search. not enough coffee.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Disregard... doh!! `inventory` versus `inventorylocation` in the search. not enough coffee